# Form to redirect to a particular URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I need a form with one input (eg. "number") that after sumbit redirects the broswer to http://staticurl/*[number]*.html
How can I do?

Comment: post your code.

Comment: do html form tutorials learn about form actions and form methods

Comment: _"I need"_ without any indication of having tried to solve the issue yourself is like begging to be downvoted and closed.

Comment: redirecting is possible with `top.location.href` (javascript after preventDefault for stopping standard form action); the form itself could redirect with action attribute, but you gave no details pr code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goTo()
{
    var NUM= document.forms[0].NUM.value;
    var URL = 'http://staticurl/'
    window.location = URL+NUM+'.jpg';
    return false;
}
</script>
```

And

```
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="return goTo()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('location:  http://staticurl/'.$_POST['number'].'html');
```

Maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Assume a HTML form like

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Now using php you can redirect

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        header("Location: http://staticurl/".$_POST['number'].".html");
    }
 ?>
```

If header() returns any error then you can do it with javascript inside php like

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo '
            <script>
                window.location.href = "http://staticurl/'.$_POST['number'].'.html";
            </script>
        ';
    }
 ?>
```

Validate the form data before processing it.